# Regex to fetch only Key Value pairs and omit some charaters

Tags: java, regex

I have this data

```
ReferenceDataLocation = as


##############################################################################
#
#   LicenseKey
#       Address Doctor License
#
##############################################################################
LicenseKey = al
```

which I'd like to capture only key value pairs eg: `ReferenceDataLocation = as` and `LicenseKey = al`

I wrote `(?xms)(^[\w]+.*?)(?=^[\w]+|\z)` regex which is perfect except the fact that it also captures `#####` part, which is not key value pair.

Please help me modify the same regex `(?xms)(^[\w]+.*?)(?=^[\w]+|\z)` to only get `ReferenceDataLocation = as` and `LicenseKey = al`

Note: [Here](http://regexr.com?2v3ut) you can try out

**Update**

I tried `(?xms)(^[\w]+.*?)(?=^[\w^#]+|\z)` it works in the [site](http://regexr.com?2v3v0) but gives me an error in java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 31
(?xms)(^[\w]+.*?)(?=^[\w^#]+|\Z)
                               ^
```

**Updat Regex that works for me**

```
(?xms)(^[\w]+.*?)(?=^[\w^\s]+|\z)
```

Comment: Just for having said so: Regular expressions are not the proper solution to parse a file. Write a solid parser instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with a simple regex-match. You can't account for occurrences like these:

```
# some words here LicenseKey = al
```

The regex engine cannot look behind from `LicenseKey` to the end of the line. This is not supported in Java's regex engine (unbounded look-behinds).

But what you posted looks like it's just a properties file. Try this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("test.properties"));
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("ReferenceDataLocation"));
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("LicenseKey"));
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("foo"));
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
as
al
null
```

Note that your input file needn't be called `test.properties`, you can give it any name you like.

And if you don't know the keys up front, you can simply iterate over all entries in your properties file like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " :: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

which prints:

```
LicenseKey :: al
ReferenceDataLocation :: as
```

And there's also `Properties#stringPropertyNames()` which returns a `Set<String>` that represents all keys in the properties file (see the API docs for more info).

See:

- Tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html
- API docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Thanks also this `(?xms)(^[\w]+.*?)(?=^[\w^\s]+|\z)` regex work. Also What if I don't know the `key` in such case how can i do it?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon, but your solution rejects a key that starts with a space (which is valid inside properties files). Don't you agree that my suggestion is far less fragile and easier to maintain? I'm a big fan of regex, but I don't see why you'd go for it in this case.

Comment: Yes thats true and I agree with your solution :) but in my case I dont know the key values

Comment: @AbhishekSimon, you don't need to know the keys. See my edited answer.